# Python - Win32Com Client Dispatch Hanging as Scheduled Tasks

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, outlook-redemption

I have a Python Script, which uses **win32com.client.dispatch** and redemption in order to connect to an instance of Outlook and harvest some data from a public folder.

When I execute this script on command line it works just fine.

Adding it as a scheduled task, it appears to get hung at the line **Outlook = win32com**

I added Event Log statements along the way to see where it is getting hung, other than that I don't have much in the way of error logs (since it doesnt actually fail)

Is there any sort of security settings I should be concerned about or anything I am not thinking of? Everything works fine with a standard python call in the CMD.

Comment: It might be a issue regarding, that "Scheduled Tasks" is a service and running in "Session 0 isolation".

Comment: Not familiar with that concept, is there any way I can check if that is the case / how can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

Scheduler runs as a service, and office apps (Outlook included) should nto be used in a service.